# How to forward all ports in docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Consider:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v /host/:/host appimage
```

it forwards *5000* to *50000*

even in multiple:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 -v /host/:/host appimage
```

What I want to know is:

```
docker run -p  allports:allports
```

is there any command available that allows to forward all ports in container? Because in my case I am running flask app. For testing purpose I want to run  multiple flask instances. So for each flask instance I want to run it in different ports. This auto multi-port forwarding would help.

Comment: Checkout the "-P" option. For this to work, your Dockerfile will have to EXPOSE a port number

Comment: I don't think there's such option. It might be very misleading. Consider well known ports e.g. If all ports are forwarded your browser wouldn't work for instance.

Answer (score 8):

You can expose a range of ports using the `-p` option, for example:

```
docker run -p 2000-5000:2000-5000 -v /host/:/host appimage
```

See the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) reference documentation for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a working set-up by using `docker run --net host ...`, in which case host's network is directly exposed to the continer and all port bindings are "public". I haven't tested this with multiple containers simultaneously but it might work just fine.

Comment: As of Docker 19 `docker run --help | grep net` returns two `--network` related options but it's not clear if those are the same suggested here.

Comment: I just found this answer, and I want to add: That might not work. `docker run --net=host` only runs on Linux. https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/ "The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."

Comment: In my experience, docker networking on non-linux systems is a pain. But that is an important clarification. Before WSL it was a lot worse (having to use for example VirtualBox to run the containers), but still it isn't great. Wow 2015 was 8 years ago!